# Operator norm of stochastic matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

$P$ a $n \times n$ stochastic matrix, that is each row is a discrete probability distribution. Let $0 \leq \alpha < 1$ and define $A = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \alpha^i P^i$. Is there an upper bound on the operator norm $\|A\|_{1,\beta}$ that is independent of $n$?

I tried writing it as

$$
\|A\|_{1,\beta} \leq \sum_{i=0}^\infty \alpha^i \|P\|_{1,\beta}^{i}
$$

But what can we say about $\|P\|_{1,\beta}$ of a stochastic matrix, particularly for $\beta = 1, 2$?

Comment: Is $\| P \|_{1,1}$ denoting $\ell_1 \to \ell_1$ operator norm? In that case it should be equal to $1$ for a stochastic matrix.

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if what I wrote above is true unless $P$ is doubly stochastic.

Comment: Does $\|A\|_{1,\beta}$ mean $\max_{\|x\|_1=1}\|Ax\|_\beta$?

Comment: @VHarisop If the columns sum up to $1$ the norm is equal $1.$

Comment: If $\|P\|_{1,1}>1$ the series $\sum a^i\|P\|_{1,1}^i $ is divergent for $a\ge \|P\|_{1,1}^{-1}$, but the series $\sum a^iP^i$ is convergent with respect to $\|\cdot \|_{1,1}$ norm.

Comment: @user1551 Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For  a $n\times n$  stochastic matrix $P$ there is no bound of $\|P\|_{1,\beta}$ independent on $n.$ Indeed let $$p_{ij}=\begin{cases} 1 & j=1\\ 0 & 2\le j\le n
\end{cases}$$
Then $$\|P\|_{1,\beta}\ge \|Pe_1\|_\beta =n^{1/\beta}$$ Actually $\|P\|_{1,\beta}=n^{1/\beta},$ as $$\displaylines{\|Px\|_\beta \le \sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|\|Pe_k\|_\beta\le \|x\|_1\max_k\|Pe_k\|_\beta \\ =\|x\|_1\|Pe_1\|_\beta=n^{1/\beta}\|x\|_1}$$
Moreover $P^k=P$ for any $k\ge 1.$ Thus
$$A=I+\sum_{i=1}^\infty a^iP=I +{a\over 1-a}P$$ and $$\|A-I\|_{1,\beta}={a\over 1-a}n^{1/\beta}$$

**Remark** If $P$ is doubly stochastic then   $$\|P\|_{1,\beta}\le \|P\|_{1,1}=1$$ and $$\|A\|_{1,\beta} \le {1\over 1-a}$$